# Specify static IP on salt-cloud profile deploy

Tags: vmware, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I've setup a new salt master and am trying to automate the deployment of new VMs with static IPs (no dhcp available) from a template.

I can deploy VMs ok using my template via a cloud profile with a default IP defined there, but I can't find a way to overwrite the IP address to use dynamically on deployment, I was hoping to pass the hostname/ip into the cli call or via the salt-api so I can initiate from an other application.

I've tried to pass the IP into a state as dynamic pillar data, this configures the vm hostname ok but couldn't see how to pass the IP into the profile as the profile conf doesn't accept pillar variables.

```
salt-call state.apply vm-new pillar='{"hostname": "salt-test", "ip": "172.0.0.11"}'
```

vm-new.sls

```
{{ pillar['hostname'] }}:
  cloud.profile:
    - name: {{ pillar['hostname'] }}
    - profile: centos7
```

cloud.profiles.d/centos7.conf

```
...
  devices:
    network:
      Network adapter 1:
        name: 'VM Network'
        switch_type: standard
        ip: 172.0.0.90
        subnet_mask: 255.255.255.0
        gateway: [172.0.0.1]
...
```

I then tried to look at using a map file but trying to pass pillar data doesn't seem to work.

```
# salt-cloud -m cloud.maps.d/centos7.map pillar='{"hostname": 'salt-test', "ip": "172.0.0.11"}'
[ERROR   ] Rendering exception occurred: Jinja variable 'salt.utils.context.NamespacedDictWrapper object' has no attribute 'hostname'
[ERROR   ] Rendering map cloud.maps.d/centos7.map failed, render error:
Jinja variable 'salt.utils.context.NamespacedDictWrapper object' has no attribute 'hostname'
No nodes defined in this map
```

centos7.map

```
    centos7:
  - {{ pillar['hostname'] }}:
      devices:
        network:
          Network adapter 1:
            ip: {{ pillar['ip'] }}
```

I have spent a while digging around the docs and github issues but couple of people trying to do similar things but hardcoded IPs in the map file solved their issue, is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? Any advice/pointers on where to look next?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar requirement wherein I needed to dynamically set some EC2 instance attributes (e.g. hostname). At least 3 months ago since this writing, this use case was not possible so I ended up building a salt exec module (e.g. `execmodule.provision_instances`) that dynamically generates a map file given my predefined profiles with default values, and eventually called `salt.cloud.CloudClient.map_run` with the generated map file.

It worked well by calling the exec module (e.g. `salt-call execmodule.provision_instances`). It would be better if we can just simply pass pillars instead of specifying a map file.

Note: Since this thread is old, salt cloud maps may already support passing pillars to map runs, please check.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested `salt.modules.win_ip.set_static_ip` for Windows VMS and it works. For example, you can run this command on salt master to set IP of all windows machines:

```
salt -G 'os_family:Windows' ip.set_static_ip 'Local Area Connection' 10.1.2.3/24 gateway=10.1.2.1
```

You can read the official doc [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_ip.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't solve my problem, I was trying to find a way to pass the IP I wanted to use before the VM is created rather than spinning up then changing the IP